# VBA Add 1 to values inside formulas for entire column

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to VBA, and attempting to automate something.

Currently, I select the entire "column F", and then use find and replace to update to the next week, so, in the example I've included, I find for 201751, and replace all with 201752. The formulas inside column F are built so that the data updates according to the new week. I do this for dozens of tabs. But If I could learn how to automate 1, i could do the rest.

I have attempted to record a Macro, of me manually doing this, but all that ends up happening is I get replace "201751 with 201752". What I'd really like to happen is to create a macro to add 1 to every value containing 2017 or 2018 contained inside column F, so replace F1 with F1+1, for all formulas contained inside F.

I'm open to any solutions, and am sure there is a better solution to this, that I'm just not aware of. Thank you so much for you help. If I haven't been clear, please let me know!

Example:

[image]

Comment: These should help you get started  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-replace-method-excel      https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/65921-vba-find-replace.html

Comment: Although I generally don't recommend using it, have you considered using the INDIRECT(..) function to allow you to specify a range using a text string? The VLOOKUP could then refer to your cell F1 that contains the week number, and you would only need to change F1 to get all the VLOOKUPS to switch to a different source sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about the following, it will take the value from cell F1, and add one to it, then replace all formulas in Column F with that new value, it will also make sure that it doesn't go to 201753, instead it will go to the next iteration as 201801:

```
Sub foo()
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("SS Lookup")
    'declare and set your worksheet, amend as required
    Findtext = ws.Range("F1")
    ReplaceText = Val(ws.Range("F1")) + 1

    If Right(ReplaceText, 2) = 53 Then
        ValueNew = Val(Left(ReplaceText, 4)) + 1
        ReplaceText = ValueNew & "01"
    End If
    ws.Columns("F").Replace what:=Findtext, replacement:=ReplaceText, lookat:=xlPart
End Sub
```

**UPDATE:**

To use the code for multiple Sheets, you could loop through them as below, in my example below it will run for all Sheets apart from one called "Main", you can add more Sheet names to the IF statement to exclude them:

```
Sub AllSheets()
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "Main" Then 'exclude Sheet named "Main"
        Findtext = ws.Range("F1")
        ReplaceText = Val(ws.Range("F1")) + 1
        If Right(ReplaceText, 2) = 53 Then
            ValueNew = Val(Left(ReplaceText, 4)) + 1
            ReplaceText = ValueNew & "01"
        End If
        ws.Columns("F").Replace what:=Findtext, replacement:=ReplaceText, lookat:=xlPart
    End If
Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. Super helpful. Is there a way to choose multiple tabs to run this for? like set ws = Sheets("SS Lookup; All Lookup; Great Value Lookup") I know this isnt the right formula, but that's what I'm trying to do now. Thanks again!

Comment: @StevenBeheshti updated my answer to loop through sheets, and exclude some of them. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This macro will clear (Delete) the formula’s from column (F:F Sheet2) and then re write the “Vlookup” formula in cell F1 adding one(1) to the “Vlookup” results and then go down to the end of column ”A” and fill down the formula in column “F”. You will need to replace the “Vlookup” statement with your own.  Column “A” must not have any blank cells.

[image]

Code:

```
Sub addone()

    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ws2.Activate
    ws2.Range("F:F").ClearContents
    ws2.[F1].Select
    ActiveCell.Value = "=VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet1!A1:B6,2,0)+1"
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, -5).End(xlDown).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).FillDown

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Further to my comment regarding the use of the INDIRECT function, here is my suggestion for amending the formulas in the cells in col F. The formulas would be re-coded using INDIRECT for the range reference to the external sheet, bringing in the Year/Week value in cell F1 into the workbook and worksheet names. So, for cell F7 (per the screen shot provided by OP), the formula would be:

```
=VLOOKUP(A7,INDIRECT("'C:\Users\behess\Documents\COLOR CASE PULL Project\RL CASE PULLS\[" & $F$1 & ".xls]" & $F$1 & "'!$A20:$H$500"), COLUMN(H:H))
```

Now, when you change the value in cell F1, the INDIRECT function re-evaluates the range reference expressed as a string, and will pick up the range from the newly-referenced workbook. This avoids needing to use any macro code to search and replace text in the formulas.

A disadvantage of INDIRECT, and the reason why I am wary of using it, is that Excel cannot Trace Precedents or Trace Dependents through the formula. However, in this case the reference is to an external workbook, so these capabilities are less useful anyway.